# Python determine file type from http form submission

Tags: python

I want to do an image form submission, and I want to validate that the image was submitted is an image server side, which is running python. Is there a simple way to do this in pure python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and naive way to do it would be with libmagic (for example the one at https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic). A better way, but it's not native Python and is a very extensive library, would be to use PIL http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/.

Comment: Does PIL do the filename for things other than images?

Comment: None of the two use the filename. Both look at the start of the file for headers they recognize and spit out the file type. PIL will also validate the image for you, that's why I said it's better.

Comment: What I'm worried about is someone submitting something that is not an Image. Will PIL still be able to see that its not an image and give the file type?

Comment: Yes. As I said, PIL is better than magic because it also validates, so someone uploading a file that has the headers of an image but contains garbage will get past file, but not past PIL.

Comment: Yes. If it cannot identify the image, it will return an error. However, you have to make sure you compile it with support for what you expect to get, otherwise it won't work (in particular, jpeg support)

Answer (score 1):

Use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/):

```
import sys
import Image

for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        im = Image.open(infile)
        print infile, im.format, "%dx%d" % im.size, im.mode
    except IOError:
        pass
```

From the docs:

> The Python Imaging Library supports a wide variety of image file
>   formats. To read files from disk, use the open function in the Image
>   module. You don't have to know the file format to open a file. The
>   library automatically determines the format based on the contents of
>   the file.